# Unable to read hdf files into R even after installing GDAL

Tags: r, gdal

I have been having reading hdf files into R (and converting them to tif). I have installed GDAL (version 2.2.3), and most of the code seem to be working fine, however I get the message NULL when trying to run *gdal_translate*.

GDAL seem to be installed fine and I am even able to use the command *get_subdatasets* (see code below) from hdf files. However, when I run *gdalUtils::gdal_translate()* I get the following message:

*NULL
Warning message:
In system(cmd, intern = TRUE) :
  running command '"C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\gdal_translate.exe" -of "GTiff"  ' had status 1*

**Here's part of my code**:

```
data_path <- "C:\\Users"



 hdf_dir <- list.files(data_path, pattern="hdf$", full.names=FALSE) #create list of names with hdf extension

 fhdf <-list.files(data_path, pattern="hdf$", full.names=TRUE)

 sds <- get_subdatasets(fhdf[1])
 gdal_translate(sds[1], dst_dataset=paste0(data_path,"\\", substr(hdf_dir[1], 1, nchar(hdf_dir[1])-4),".tif"))
```

Comment: Maybe you are missing system libraries that handle tiff files?

Comment: I have the same issue, have you solved it?